# Spinnaker for job deployments?

Tags: spinnaker

Does anyone use Spinnaker for deployment of short running jobs, similar in spirit to what [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/) or [Nomad](https://www.nomadproject.io/docs/job-specification/index.html) do? If so, how do they do it? If not, are there any plans to support it one day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kubernetes provider specifically supports a Run Job stage in a pipeline that allows execution of a container that is expected to run to completion.

Similarly there is an option to run a jenkins job as a stage which I've seen teams use to execute arbitrary work (not just CI type of tasks)

Comment: That's pretty interesting... has anyone published any resources/presentations that discuss in more details?

Comment: where can I find more about the ways to exucute arbitrary work in Spinnaker (bash, python, gcloud command, etc)?